# Why does the law of cosine not work in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In class, we derived the dot product formula using the cosine law in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$.
Then, we found the Cauchy-Schwarz theorem and the Triangle Inequality theorem.
Then, we defined the concept of angle in $\mathbb R^n$. My teacher specifically said not to use the cosine law in $\mathbb R^n$.

This does NOT make sense to me. We just used the cos law to find the formula that we generalized in $\mathbb R^n$. Why is it that it does not work? I tried to do some scribblings and I found out that he was right. How does that even happen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cosine law and the triangle inequality hold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any integer $n \ge 1$. Can you show us your work?

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I just redid my calculation. Turns out I was right, but I still have suspicions if the vectors he chose and the numbers she chose were taken from R^2 or R^3. I'll upload the question.

Comment: If the norm of a=3 and the norm of b=5, and 3a+b has a norm of 10, find the angle of a and b.

Comment: Basically, what I did is:
10^2=(Norm of (3a))^2+(Norm of b)^2-2(Norm of 3a)(norm of b)cos($/theta$).

(Sorry, I don't know LaTex.) I isolated theta which gave me about 1.64, the right answer in radians.

Is it right? Anything wrong?

Comment: You should include these details in the question instead of posting them as comments.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Teachers have been known to say things that don't make sense, but sometimes what they say is misinterpreted by the student.  You should ask your teacher for clarification.  But the cosine law **does** work perfectly well in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

Comment: Ok perfect. It's very possible that I misheard or did not understand (even more probable ;) ). I will definitely check with the teacher.